# Broadcasting with multiple parameters in grid search

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of arrays that looks something like this:

```
list_of_arrays = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

At the same time I have `weights` for each `int` in each array, which I need to calculate the weighted average, e.g:

```
weights = [1, 20, 100, 10]
```

Now I wish to compute the weighted average like:

```
numpy.average(list_of_arrays, weights=weights, axis=1)
```

The results for this will be:

```
[2.90839695 3.90839695 4.90839695]
```

Which is just the weighted average for each array.

However, my issue is that my weights are actually not just a list. In reality it looks something like:

```
weights_true = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 10, 15, 20], [50, 100, 150, 200], [5, 10, 15, 20]]
```

So instead of getting just one list of values for one particular set of weights, I need a list of values for each combination of weights that can be created from `weights_true`.

Can that be achieved in some way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the weighted averages manually using broadcasting:

```
(list_of_arrays*weights_true[:,None]).sum(2)/weights_true[:,None].sum(2)
```

with a simpler form using an intermediate reshaped weights array:

```
W = weights_true[:,None]
(list_of_arrays*W).sum(2)/W.sum(2)
```

output:

```
array([[3., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 5.]])
```

Comment: But shouldn't I be getting an array for each set of weights ? Here it looks like I only get 4.

Comment: Well, you have a ndarray, so 4 arrays of size 3? What would be your expected output?

Comment: For instance, in my first example I have an array of one set of weights. If each weight can have 4 values, there should be something like 4x4x4x4 combinations (don't know if that is entirely true). Hence I would need the same amount of arrays ?